# Setting up scheduled actions in process builder: "Do you want to execute action..." not showing up

Tags: process-builder, action

I'm trying to setup a scheduled action when a lead is created or updated. [This salesforce trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/business_process_automation/process_builder) tells me I need to check the box "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?", which is supposed to be in the advanced menu.

However, for me the only option in the advanced menu is to enable recursion (see screenshot). Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is your screenshot?

Comment: Woops forgot the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the wrong element. The flow's Object element allows you to specify recursion, while the flow's Criteria element allows you to specify if you only want to trigger when the conditions are met.